# Is the phrase "more and more x the more y" idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Is the phrase "more and more x the more y" idiomatic? I think it is, but it's hard for me to know if it's the case and if there are some constraint to the phrase and how we can use it.

For example:

> He became more and more angry the more the audience ignored him.
>
> The vampire became more and more powerful the more blood he drank from
>   his victims.
>
> The legend became more and more widespread the more time went on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is idiomatic:

***[more and more:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+and+more)***

> an increasing amount; additional amounts.
>
> - As I learn more and more, I see how little I really know. Dad seems to be smoking more and more lately.

***[the more (one thing happens), the more (another thing happens)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+more+(one+thing+happens)%2C+the+more+(another+thing+happens))***

> An increase in one thing (an action, occurrence, etc.) causes or correlates to an increase in another thing.
>
> - The more work you do now, the more free time you'll have this weekend.

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.)

(Farlex Dictionary of Idioms.)

Comment: Very good answer.